# Vonage OpenTok iOS Swift: Subscribers count is zero in case of Publisher

Tags: ios, swift, opentok, vonage

I have just download Multi-party example and install in 3 different devices with a same session token. (**Media Mode**: **Routed**)

Also, I have created 1 publisher and 2 subscribers generate token and added in code.

I am getting a stream/video of a publisher in all subscriber devices screen.

But in publisher, I am not getting a stream/video and audio of subscribers ?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var endCallButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var swapCameraButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var muteMicButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var userName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var subscribers: [IndexPath: OTSubscriber] = [:]

    lazy var session: OTSession = {
        return OTSession(
            apiKey: kApiKey,
            sessionId: kSessionId,
            delegate: self
            )!
    }()

    lazy var publisher: OTPublisher = {
        let settings = OTPublisherSettings()
        settings.name = UIDevice.current.name
        return OTPublisher(delegate: self, settings: settings)!
    }()

    var error: OTError?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.session.connect(withToken: kToken, error: &error)
        self.userName.text = UIDevice.current.name
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        guard let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else {
            return
        }
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.collectionView.bounds.size.width / 2,
                                 height: self.collectionView.bounds.size.height / 2)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func swapCameraAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let previousPosition = self.publisher.cameraPosition
        self.publisher.cameraPosition = previousPosition == .front ? .back : .front
    }

    @IBAction func muteMicAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.publisher.publishAudio = !publisher.publishAudio

        let buttonImage: UIImage  = {
            if !self.publisher.publishAudio {
                return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "mic_muted-24")
            } else {
                return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "mic-24")
            }
        }()

        self.muteMicButton.setImage(buttonImage, for: .normal)
    }

    @IBAction func endCallAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.session.disconnect(&error)
    }

}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func reloadCollectionView() {
        print("self.subscribers.count: \(self.subscribers.count)")
        self.collectionView.isHidden = self.subscribers.count == 0
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.subscribers.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withReuseIdentifier: "subscriberCell",
            for: indexPath
            ) as! SubscriberCollectionCell
        cell.subscriber = self.subscribers[indexPath]
        return cell
    }
}



// MARK: - OpenTok Methods
extension ViewController {

    func doPublish() {
        self.swapCameraButton.isEnabled = true
        self.muteMicButton.isEnabled = true
        self.endCallButton.isEnabled = true

        if let pubView = self.publisher.view {
            let publisherDimensions = CGSize(width: view.bounds.size.width / 4,
                                             height: view.bounds.size.height / 6)
            pubView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:collectionView.bounds.size.width - publisherDimensions.width,
                                                   y:collectionView.bounds.size.height - publisherDimensions.height + collectionView.frame.origin.y),
                                   size: publisherDimensions)
            view.addSubview(pubView)

        }

        self.session.publish(self.publisher, error: &error)
    }

    func doSubscribe(to stream: OTStream) {
        if let subscriber = OTSubscriber(stream: stream, delegate: self) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.subscribers.count, section: 0)
            self.subscribers[indexPath] = subscriber
            self.session.subscribe(subscriber, error: &error)
            self.reloadCollectionView()
        }
    }

    func findSubscriber(byStreamId id: String) -> (IndexPath, OTSubscriber)? {
        for (_, entry) in self.subscribers.enumerated() {
            if let stream = entry.value.stream, stream.streamId == id {
                return (entry.key, entry.value)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func findSubscriberCell(byStreamId id: String) -> SubscriberCollectionCell? {
        for cell in collectionView.visibleCells {
            if let subscriberCell = cell as? SubscriberCollectionCell,
                let subscriberOfCell = subscriberCell.subscriber,
                (subscriberOfCell.stream?.streamId ?? "") == id {
                return subscriberCell
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}

// MARK: - OTSession delegate callbacks
extension ViewController: OTSessionDelegate {

    func sessionDidConnect(_ session: OTSession) {
        print("Session connected")
        doPublish()
    }

    func sessionDidDisconnect(_ session: OTSession) {
        print("Session disconnected")
        self.subscribers.removeAll()
        reloadCollectionView()
    }

    func session(_ session: OTSession, streamCreated stream: OTStream) {
        print("Session streamCreated: \(stream.streamId)")
        if self.subscribers.count == 4 {
            print("Sorry this sample only supports up to 4 self.subscribers :)")
            return
        }
        self.doSubscribe(to: stream)
    }

    func session(_ session: OTSession, streamDestroyed stream: OTStream) {
        print("Session streamDestroyed: \(stream.streamId)")

        guard let (index, subscriber) = self.findSubscriber(byStreamId: stream.streamId) else {
            return
        }
        subscriber.view?.removeFromSuperview()
        self.subscribers.removeValue(forKey: index)
        self.reloadCollectionView()
    }

    func session(_ session: OTSession, didFailWithError error: OTError) {
        print("session Failed to connect: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

// MARK: - OTPublisher delegate callbacks
extension ViewController: OTPublisherDelegate {

    func publisher(_ publisher: OTPublisherKit, streamCreated stream: OTStream) {
        print("Publisher streamCreated")
        //TESTING
        self.reloadCollectionView()
    }

    func publisher(_ publisher: OTPublisherKit, streamDestroyed stream: OTStream) {
        print("Publisher streamDestroyed")
    }

    func publisher(_ publisher: OTPublisherKit, didFailWithError error: OTError) {
        print("Publisher failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

// MARK: - OTSubscriber delegate callbacks
extension ViewController: OTSubscriberDelegate {

    func subscriberDidConnect(toStream subscriberKit: OTSubscriberKit) {
        print("Subscriber connected")
        self.reloadCollectionView()
    }

    func subscriber(_ subscriber: OTSubscriberKit, didFailWithError error: OTError) {
        print("Subscriber failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func subscriberVideoDataReceived(_ subscriber: OTSubscriber) {
        print("Subscriber subscriberVideoDataReceived")
    }

}
```

Even I tried to console log subscribers count in publisher,
 I am getting 0.

What I am missing, I need subscriber videos and count ??

Comment: Manik here from the Video team. I don't think you need if let when creating a subscriber. You can create subscriber = OTSubscriber(stream, delegate); Can you confirm you're not receiving errors when subscribing to the stream? Are you adding the subscriber view? I

Comment: this is your provided simple multiparty example, i just copied